# How to set light status bar for Android N

Tags: android

I use this way to set light status bar for `Android M`, and it works well:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {                    
     activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);

}
```

But, it does not work at `Android N`. The words in status bar are still white. Is it a bug? Or is there any way to set light status bar at `Android N`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the question.It did works to set light status bar mode.But after that, i changed the status bar's color, called setSystemUiVisibility() again and set other value.So the light status bar is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just call this method from any activity and pass color code too

```
public static void makeStatusBarLight(Activity activity, int color) {
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        window.setStatusBarColor(color);
    }
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

}
```

call like this

makeStatusBarLight(BaseActivity.this, getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor));